# Problem in Calling VF Page as PDF in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, pdf

visualforce page cannot be called to salesforce1
We have created a visualforce page on a custom object (invoices) that is rendered as PDF to issue the invoice. Our code is

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice1__c" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf" language="tr">

<meta content="text/html; charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="width: 640px;" table-border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td border-color="#000000" style="width: 400px; height: 245px;">

            </td>
            <td height:="" style="border-color=" text-align:="" width:="">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
// our main html code calling SFDC fields to page layout //

</apex:page>
```

pdf displays on desktop and fullsite view in any mobile device. However if I try to display the same page in the the Salesforce1 by calling the page from a custom button on my cusom object (invoices) page doesn't render and the animated circular fetch gif keeps moving & the page never loads.

Creating an empty Visualforce Page, with renderAs="PDF" also does not work in sf1.

When I press the back arrow on the app, the it shows just 1/4 of the pdf but it can't be scrolled to any direction and seems like a frozen image.

We appreciare any idea or feedback toresolve or workaround this problem

Regards

Answer (score 3):

There is a known bug which exist: 
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4isAAC